# Await/Async or SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

So I've allready written a tcp-server with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` and socket.***Async methods. But I do love the `await/async` way of writing code using the `Stream.ReadAsync` and `Stream.WriteAsync` methods.

Is there any difference performance/memory wise, or do I simply make a difference in syntax?

Comment: The only good reason to use the SocketAsyncEventArgs API is for very high traffic/low latency servers to reduce the amount of work GC has to perform. I generally wouldn't consider using it until I saw measurable memory problems using the other APIs. That said, I believe Stephen Toub created some wrappers around the SocketAsyncEventArgs API for async/await. I'll dig out a link.

Comment: Tada!! : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx

Comment: BTW, the reason I recommend against using the SocketAsyncEventArgs API is because of the added complexity surrounding the pooling of the SocketAsyncEventArgs instances recommended by MS. It makes fairly ugly reading... To givew you a measure of performance, we run servers with ~10000 permanently connected clients using the Stream apis with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: What kind of hardware on those servers? EC2's?
How about you transfer these comments into an answer eh?

Comment: You still haven't answered my hardware question. Also, if you could provide theese comments as an answer, I can accept it :)

Comment: Using the samples in [Stephen Toub's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx), I wrote some classes for awaiting asynchronous socket operations, caching arguments and managing buffers without fragmentation. You can find it [here](https://github.com/safakgur/Dawn.SocketAwaitable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of using the socketasynceventargs is to reduce strain on the garbage collector and to keep the buffers of the sockets grouped to prevent out of memory exception.

By using a pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs, you can eliminate the need to create and collect the IAsyncResult for every call to read and write.

Secondly, each SocketAsyncEventArgs can be assigned a portion of a large byte[] block. This prevents memory fragmentation which helps reduce the memory footprint. Although this can technically also be done with the Begin/End calls, it is easier to permenantly assign each SocketAsyncEventArgs with its own buffer instead of assigning a block every time that a read or write is called with the Begin/End methods.

One last difference that can be important is that according to the MSDN Library, the Begin/End Send method may block while the socket buffer is full. The SocketAsyncEventArgs will not block, instead, only a certain amount of bytes will be written depending on the amount of space in the sockets buffer, the callback will specify the amount of bytes written.

The advantages are really not noticeable unless it is an edge case. Unless you run into either of the problems specified, I suggest that you choose what is most comfortable and maintainable for you.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to be jumping into the question years later. Can the benefit of the SocketAsyncEventArgs be replaced with Memory<byte> and ReadOnlySpan<byte>?